How do I create an empty copy of your Chart of Accounts in Gnucash?
I'm trying to create an empty chart of accounts as described at https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Closing_Books. It says: create an empty copy of your Chart of Accounts by selecting File->Export->Accounts. I do that, however the exported file is not empty, it contains all previous transactions. Effectively a copy of my current file.
How do I get an empty copy? Thank you

Did you first follow the instructions further up the page about closing the accounts?

This is actually pretty easy to do, by simply following the steps that you set out in the question.
Start by opening your working file in GnuCash.  It will open with all of the transactions in place in all of the accounts.  Now, from the File menu, choose the Export option, then the Export Accounts item on the sub-menu.  This will open a Save-As dialogue box.
You'll need to specify a location for the file that you want to save, and give it an appropriate name.  Unless you have a reason to do otherwise, I suggest that you specify the Data Format as xml (top of screen) and the display file types as Datafiles only (bottom of screen).  Those options will probably be already selected.  Press Save As.
In my implementation of GnuCash, that process outputs a GnuCash database with the same Chart of Accounts as my source working file, but no transactions.
I can't explain why the same process would not work for you.
